# Jenkins Developer environment virtual machine using the same agent machines

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

We are trying to setup a virtual machine environment complete with build tools, sql server, etc to allow development teams to have unique CI environments (both code and DB to allow functional verification). We have created this machine with everything installed (visual studio tools, sql server, etc) along with a couple of agent agents on other machines for performing unique tasks like redgate sql compare sync,etc. Our idea is to create a VMWare template of this machine.  Each DEV team could spin up one of these machines and develop/verify on their unique branch which will be configured while the virtual machine is being spun up.

My question is how can we have several of these machines that have jenkins server, use the same agent machines.  I don't want to reconfigure new agents at spin up but have the new VMs use the existing agents.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Docker**, I think it will fulfill your requirements.

> "Setup Jenkins master and Build Slaves as Docker Container" :-
> https://devopscube.com/jenkins-master-build-slaves-docker-container/

I hope this link is helpful.